# How to unprotect xlsx document structure in excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with my macro which is failed on attempt to UnfreezePanes. The document has structure protection: View > Protect Workbook > Structure and windows protection (for 2013 version)

In excel versions before 2013 I do not have problems with the macro:

```
Sub Unfreeze()
    ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
End Sub
```

But in 2013 version I faced a problem when 'ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect' is executed without errors but does not cancel structure change restrictions from the document because the newt row `ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False` throws :

> error 1004 'Application-defined or object-definited error'.

Moreover FreezePanes button on the Ribbon is locked even after pressing the button 'Enable Editing' which popups each time when I open the document.

[image: Enable Editing button]

After pressing the button 'Enable editing' I go to VBE and execute 'ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect' and then I still see the document is protected: View > Protect Workbook > Structure is checked. So my attempts to remove the protection not directly from this window are failed. But! I am not able to remove the protection even from this window! When I uncheck the checkbox 'Structure' the button [Ok] becomes unavaileble! The protection does not have a password because even when I type some symbols in the password field a still unable to press [Ok] button while 'Structure' checkbox is unchecked.

[image: Unable to unlock]

Please note the problem is reproducible in excel 2013 and it will be great if you advice how to unlock the document using vba code.

[Example of the document can be found here](http://cloud.mail.ru/public/Kiz8/zY39rnKEc)

Comment: fwiw, I do not experience this behavior on a new Excel 2013 workbook but did on yours (even after Unblocking with Explorer, Right-click, Properties). The only way I could access the Freeze/Unfreeze command was to copy the worksheet to a new workbook.

Answer (score 1):

The workbook may be partially unprotected but it retains a digital signature.

[image: digital_signature]

Click File ► Info ► Protect Workbook ► Add a digital signature for details. Changing it or removing it altogether quickly recovered the ability to Freeze/Unfreeze pane(s).

Comment: Thank you Jeeped for the answer! Is there the only way to deal with digital signature? Following your steps I get 'Get a Digital ID' popup which redirects me to support.office.com > Find Digital ID services and there are no any other windows like you attached.

[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LGB0n.png

Comment: Try running this from the VBE's Immediate window (Ctrl+G) `ActiveWorkbook.Signatures.AddNonVisibleSignature "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"`.

Comment: [Add or remove a digital signature in Office files](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-remove-a-digital-signature-in-Office-files-70d26dc9-be10-46f1-8efa-719c8b3f1a2d?CorrelationId=73f5192e-e2ed-403b-a863-a6b4bb98abe4&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Comment: still the same - popup message asking me to get a digital ID :(

Answer (score 0):

With excel files from previous versions of excel I have had activesheet.unprotect change the activesheet in E2013.

Maybe if you try qualifing the call to unprotect with the workbook name and the same with the freezepanes call?

I have not tested it .